# Accumulated instance count of each list element

Tags: list-manipulation, map, counting

Given a list with repeated elements, for example:

```
list = {m, i, s, s, i, s, s, i, p, p, i}
```

I'd like to determine, for each position in the list, how many times the element at that position has appeared in the list up to and including that position.

That is, I'd like to define a function `f` such that, for my example `list` above,

```
f[list] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4}
```

Notice that

- `f[list]〚1〛= 1` because position 1 is the **first** `m` in the list
- `f[list]〚5〛= 2` because position 5 is the **second** `i` in the list
- `f[list]〚7〛= 4` because position 7 is the **fourth** `s` in the list
- `f[list]〚9〛= 1` because position 9 is the **first** `p` in the list
- etc.

This seems like the kind of thing there could well be a built-in for already, but I wouldn't have any guesses as to what it would be called or how to search for it. If not, is there a simple way to implement it? (Probably involving `MapIndexed`, I'd guess.)

Comment: `Table[Count[Take[list, j], list[[j]]], {j, 1, Length@list}]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {m, i, s, s, i, s, s, i, p, p, i};

Count[list[[1 ;; #]], list[[#]]] & /@ Range@Length@list

Length /@ (DeleteCases[list[[1 ;; #]], Except[list[[#]]]] & /@ 
   Range@Length@list)

MapIndexed[Count[list[[1 ;; First@#2]], #1] &, list]

ReplaceList[list, {x__, y___} -> {x}] // Map[Count[#, Last@#] &]

Length /@ (PositionIndex[list[[1 ;; #]]][list[[#]]] & /@ 
   Range@Length@list)

TakeList[list, {#}] & /@ Range@Length@list // Map[First] // 
 Map[Count[#, Last@#] &]

Reverse@ReplaceList[
  Reverse@list, {___, x_, y___} :> Count @@ {{x, y}, x}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4}

Comment: `MapIndexed[Count[list[[1 ;; First@#2]], #1] &, list]` is the one I was halfway to formulating in my head. Not surprised that there are many possible approaches…but I am surprised that none of them is very legible! Assuming that nobody comes along with an even cleverer idea than any of these, that is.

Comment: Of these, do you have a favorite?

Comment: Depends on the time of the day or the phase of the moon.

Comment: The `Count[list〚1 ;; #〛, list〚#〛] &` option is what I ultimately went with as it was, IMO, the clearest, from among all the options everyone presented, to see at a glance what it was doing.

Answer (score 12):

```
accumulateCounts := Module[{c$}, c$[_] = 0; Map[PreIncrement@*c$]]

accumulateCounts @ {m, i, s, s, i, s, s, i, p, p, i}
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Using an `Association` - counter:

```
list = {m, i, s, s, i, s, s, i, p, p, i};

c = <|# -> 0 & /@ Union @ list|>;

++c[#] & /@ list
```

{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4}

Thank you, AsukaMinato, for proposing the following definition of `c`:

```
Module[{c = AssociationMap[0 &] @ list}, ++c[#] & /@ list]
```

{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4}

Comment: `c = list // AssociationMap[0&];` also works

Comment: A very nice short form, thank you

Comment: slightly shorter: `c = 0 Counts @ list`.

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {m, i, s, s, i, s, s, i, p, p, i};

Permute[Flatten[Ordering /@ Split@Sort@#], Ordering@#]&@list

(* {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just more variations...

```
Normal[SparseArray[Flatten[MapIndexed[#1 -> #2[[1]] &] /@ Values@PositionIndex[list]]]]

Values[SortBy[Flatten[MapIndexed[#1 -> #2[[1]] &] /@ Values@PositionIndex[list]], First]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using `PositionIndex` and `ReplacePart`:

```
pos = Values[PositionIndex[list]];
rep = Catenate[Thread /@ Thread[# -> Range[Length@#] & /@ #] &@pos];
ReplacePart[list, rep]

(*{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 MapThread[Replace[#1,#2]&,{list,Counts@Take[list,#]&/@Range@Length@list}]


(* {1,1,1,2,2,3,4,3,1,2,4} *)
```